# Terminal Window Is Having Icon of itself over Close, Minimize, and Maximize Buttons

Tags: icons, gnome-terminal, window, titlebar

Check The Terminal Window - 'Minimize, Maximize, Close' buttons are covered by the icon:

[image: screenshot]